# Ways to place tiles on an $8\times8$ board.

Tags: combinatorics

> How many ways are there to place, in an 8x8 board, 6 red tiles where they can't be in the same row or column, and 5 different coloured tiles (not red), which must all be in the same row.

**Attempt:**

1) Pick 6 rows out of the 8 for the red tiles $\binom 8 6$

2) Pick 6 columns for the red tiles: $\binom 8 6$

3) I have to place the 5 differently coloured tiles, I sepparate in two cases:

i) I place them in rows that have a red tile $\binom 6 1$, I pick the places for the 5 tiles $\binom 7 5$, I permute them $5!$.

ii) I place them in rows that don't have a red tile $\binom 2 1$, I pick the places for the 5 tiles $\binom 8 5$, I permute them $5!$.

Answer: $$\binom 8 6 ^2 \left( 6\cdot \binom 7 5\cdot 5!+2\cdot \binom 8 5\cdot 5! \right)$$

Is this correct?

Comment: I see a couple of flaws, first of all selecting the columns and rows the red tiles occupy does not uniquely determine the positions, you need to multiply by $6!$.

Comment: Why is that? All the red tiles are indistinguishable

Comment: well, Placing $(1,0)$ and $(0,1)$ is not the same as $(1,1)$ and $(0,0)$ athough the same rows and columns are used.

Comment: Oh, damn. I understand, thanks dream.

Comment: What dREaM says is that your answer is too small by the factor $6!$.

Comment: well, I mean that is one mistake, although I see some other mistakes.

Comment: but with that change you have counted the number of ways to place the red counters correctly.

Comment: Oh wait nevermind, it looks good now.

Comment: You mean that was the only mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first part is not correct. Remember that just choosing the columns and rows for the red tiles is not enough.

Here, we choose the first 6 rows and the first 6 columns:

```
o-------
-o------
--o-----
---o----
----o---
-----o--
--------
--------
```

Here, we also choose the first 6 rows and the first 6 columns:

```
-----o--
----o---
---o----
--o-----
-o------
o-------
--------
--------
```

Clearly, they are different, even though you haven't accounted for them. The rest of your answer, however, should be right.

When tackling these problems, make sure to actually visualize the choices in your head so that you understand how exactly you're counting up the results. There are many different counting approaches to almost every problem, but at the end of the day, anything countable you can list out. Combinatorics at its heart is simply organizing these lists and then using methods to count efficiently.

Comment: Effectively, choosing rows for the red tiles in step $1)$ makes them distinguishable, so you should treat them as distinguishable in step $2)$.